# Issue with importing a database into phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am learning how to use SQL, I set up a localhost, in the course of that journey, I was confronted to the issue of importing sql files into phpMyAdmin, I did the right click on `config.inc.php` and clicked on the Notepad++ that I previously installed, I typed in there the following code: `$cfg['UploadDir']='c:\Files';`, of course I created on the hard drive C the `Files` directory. Now that I came back into phpMyAdmin, clicked on my database, clicked on import, this is what I got as message:

> The directory you set for upload work cannot be reached.

Can anyone help me here with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver probably doesn't have permission to read `'c:\Files'` thus it is not a valid directory. Technically you would say this is out of the web root.

I suggest you set the upload directory to a subdirectory of your web server's root directory (or in the PHPMyAdmin web directory). Then if for your own ease of use you want it to be located at `'c:\Files'` you can create a shortcut from the web root upload directory whatever you name it, and place the shortcut in `'c:'` and name it `'Files'`.